# Play audio file when download complete in iPad using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, ipad, audio

I am developing a Cordova based application.I have a "Notification.wav" audio file in the resources . I want to play this file using javascript when my downloadSucess method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//init your audio
var audioDownloadComplete = new Audio('assets/Notification.wav');

//play it on complete
var onDownloadComplete = function(){
    audioDownloadComplete.play();
}
```

Comment: I had my wav file in the resource folder. Still you want me to have the path as assets/notify.wav

Comment: My example is based on www/index.html, www/app.js, www/assets/notify.wav and your app.js is referenced from your index.